# Docker container app service in azure. How to use DefaultAzureCredential for keyvault

Tags: azure, containers, azure-keyvault, defaultazurecredential

I have a container app service running in azure and it works fine.

However if i want to run this container locally it fails because it cant authenticate to read the key vault in azure.

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
{
    var builtConfig = config.Build();

    string SecretUri = $"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/";
    var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(SecretUri), new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true }));
    config.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
})
```

When running in azure the DefaultAzureCredential will inherit its permissions from the app service and that works fine.

However if i want to run the container locally for testing outside of azure it doesnt know what permissions to use.
How should i handle this? Can i somehow tell the container what permissions to use without making dev changes to the container?

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I typically store the default Azure Key Vault development credentials in **User Settings** locally when I develop in Visual Studio. Then I put the same credentials as environment variables in Azure App Services. Then it will work in both places, if the credentials are named the same.

You access the local user secrets by right-click on the project in Visual Studio

[image]

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows) for more details.

Comment: But then you have credentials in environmental variables which is not secure, and then defeats the purpose of having a azure key vault.

Comment: But you have to trust Azure in this case. You have to get the identity/credentials into the container somehow....  but sure, if the container is hacked, they are exposed. That's why it can be useful to have different key vaults for different applications to limit the damage. Native Azure services can access AKV using Azure identities. but i am not sure about how you get that credential inside the container where you app is.

Answer (score 0):

The `DefaultAzureCredential` will try several credential types in order as show [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet), so if don't set the environment variable and exclude the `SharedTokenCacheCredential` with `ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true`, it will use `VisualStudioCredential` to auth, i.e. the user account you logged in VS.

To make it work locally, you need to add your user account to the `Access Policies` of the keyvault with correct permissions, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal). (Or if you select [`Azure role-based access control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault#data-plane-and-azure-rbac-preview) in `Access policies` blade of the keyvault, the RBAC role `Key Vault Administrator` is needed, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal) to add it.) After adding it , it will work fine.